# Determining the type of the template parameter method argument

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, template-argument-deduction

There are many IEnumXXXX type COM interfaces that have a pure virtual method Next, like this:

```
IEnumString : IUnknown {
...
virtual HRESULT Next(ULONG, LPOLESTR*, ULONG*) = 0;
...
};

IEnumGUID : IUnknown {
...
virtual HRESULT Next(ULONG, GUID*, ULONG*) = 0;
...
};
```

Need a template, like this:

```
enum_value_type<IEnumString>::type // LPOLESTR
enum_value_type<IEnumGUID>::type   // GUID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something along these lines:

```
template <typename T> struct ExtractArgType;

template <typename C, typename T>
struct ExtractArgType<HRESULT (C::*)(ULONG, T*, ULONG*)>{
    using type = T;
};

template <typename IEnum>
struct enum_value_type {
    using type = typename ExtractArgType<decltype(&IEnum::Next)>::type;
};
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/51fTfGPYx)